# Get n non overlapping m-sized samples from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, sample

Given an array, how can I extract `n` non overlapping random samples of size `m` from it?

For example, given the array:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
```

calling `sample(arr, 3, 2)` would for example return `[[7, 8], [4, 5], [2, 3]]`, calling `sample(arr, 2, 4)` would necessarily return `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]`, and calling `sample(arr, 5, 2)` would throw an error.

EDIT - Maybe this wasn't clear in the initial question: samples should be lists of contiguous elements. That is why `sample(arr, 2, 4)` can only return `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]` and not `[[2, 3, 1, 6], [5, 4, 7, 8]`, for example.

Comment: What happens if you do `sample(arr, 20, 40)` or even `sample(arr, 5, 2)` etc?

Comment: @Dominik An error should probably be thrown, will edit.

Comment: Can `sample(arr, 2, 4)` also return `[[5,6,7,8], [1,2,3,4]]`? I assumed it would in my answer, because `sample(arr, 3, 2)` returns `[[7,8], [4,5], [2,3]]` which is a seemingly random sample order.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Yes, but that is not a necessary step. The final array doesn't need to be shuffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start off by first creating a list with the format of the return value:

```
[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8]
[<---->, <---->, <---->, <>, <>] // sample(array, 3, 2)
[<------------>, <------------>] // sample(array, 2, 4)
```

These format arrays could be written out using the lengths:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[   2,    2,    2, 1, 1] // sample(array, 3, 2)
[         4,          4] // sample(array, 2, 4)
```

Then shuffle the format arrays to gain a random sample selection:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[   2, 1,    2,    2, 1] // sample(array, 3, 2)
[         4,          4] // sample(array, 2, 4)
```

Then for each element of the format array, remove the the first `n` elements from the input array. Then store them unless it was a filler (one size chunks that are put in to reach the array length).

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[[1,2], [4,5], [6,7]]  // sample(array, 3, 2)
[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]] // sample(array, 2, 4)
```

Lastly shuffle the resulting samples.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[[4,5], [1,2], [6,7]]  // sample(array, 3, 2)
[[5,6,7,8], [1,2,3,4]] // sample(array, 2, 4)
```

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
console.log(sample(arr, 3, 2));
console.log(sample(arr, 2, 4));
console.log(sample(arr, 5, 2));

function randomInt(limit) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * limit);
}

function shuffle(array) {
  for (let limit = array.length; limit > 0; --limit)
    array.push(...array.splice(randomInt(limit), 1));
}

function sample(array, sampleCount, sampleLength) {
  let elementCount = sampleCount * sampleLength;
  if (elementCount > array.length)
    throw "invalid sampleCount/sampleLength arguments";
    
  const filler = {valueOf: () => 1};
  const fillerCount = array.length - elementCount;
  const lengths = Array.from(
    {length: sampleCount + fillerCount},
    (_, i) => i < sampleCount ? sampleLength : filler
  );

  shuffle(lengths);
  const samples = Array.from(array);
  for (const length of lengths) {
    const sample = samples.splice(0, length);
    if (length === filler) continue;
    samples.push(sample);
  }
  shuffle(samples);
  
  return samples;
}
```

Note that `===` is important in `length === filler`. If you use `==`, `filler` would also equal `1`. This would then conflict with a call like `sample(array, 5, 1)` where each sample length is `1`.

```js
const filler = {valueOf: () => 1};

console.log("1 == filler       //=>", 1 == filler);
console.log("2 == filler       //=>", 2 == filler);
console.log("filler == filler  //=>", filler == filler);
console.log("1 === filler      //=>", 1 === filler);
console.log("2 === filler      //=>", 2 === filler);
console.log("filler === filler //=>", filler == filler);
```

Comment: Really liked this approach. Also learned the `{valueOf: () => 1}` trick, which is useful. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) is useful if you want to create you own "complex" number. It is invoked automatically when a number is expected. For example `4 + complexObject` would call the `valueOf` function to retrieve a value.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a greedy algorithm, and take m-sized n tuples from the shuffled array:

```js
const arr = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
function sample(arr, length, size){
  if(arr.length < length*size)
    throw new Error("too short");
  arr.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
  let res = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) res.push(arr.slice(i*size, i*size+size));
  return res;
}
console.log(sample(arr, 2, 4));
```

Comment: Where is the random sampling?

Comment: @cabralpinto added a line to shuffle the array

Comment: @cabralpinto also with "non overlapping" you mean that you don't take the same value more than once?

Comment: This solutions just takes the first n non overlapping m-sized samples, not random ones.

Comment: yes, no sample should contain the same value as another one. Except of course in case the array has repeated values.

Comment: @cabralpinto but why `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]` is the only solution then?... why for example `[[9, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 1]` is not valid?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best implementation would shuffle first. Here's my two cents:

```js
function shuffle(array){
  let a = array.slice(), i = a.length, n, h;
  while(i){
    n = Math.floor(Math.random()*i--); h = a[i]; a[i] = a[n]; a[n] = h;
  }
  return a;
}
function sample(array, chunks, count){
  const r = [], a = shuffle(array);
  for(let n=0; n<chunks; n++){
    r.push(a.splice(0, count));
  }
  return r;
}
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
console.log(sample(arr, 3, 2)); console.log(sample(arr, 2, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Rando.js](https://github.com/nastyox/Rando.js) (which is cryptographically secure), [map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp), and [splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) pretty easily. Just use randojs' `randoSequence` function to shuffle the provided array and splice `n` size-`m` arrays out of that shuffled array to get everything we need to return. If the provided array has too few values, the later arrays that we return will just be shorter.

```js
function sample(arr, n, m){
  arr = randoSequence(arr).map(i => i.value), sample = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) sample[i] = arr.splice(-m);
  return sample;
}

console.log(sample([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 3, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/2.0.0.js"></script>
```